# Making xml file comply with schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML file which *almost* comply with an xml schema.
Almost meaning that all the elements are there, but the *order (sequence)* of the elements does not comply with the schema.

Is there a tool to do this? Either something from a prompt or something built into C#.
Serializing things using a schema would be the nicest thing.
I start out from Entity Framework, where I get things out with a lot of extra namespaces and elements which I xml transform away/to something else. I've been able to change or remove everything now, except the order of the elements.

I've experimented a bit with xsl transformation, but am definitely a noob here.

I'm quite new to XML and all that jazz, so please bear with me.

Comment: There are tools to validate XML instances online, and also to generate valid instances from schemas. There are many. Try a search.

Comment: I've searched high and low.
I now also tried to
1) Generate C# classes from the schema

Comment: 2) Serialize those classes.
Sadly, while the elements are in order in the class, the XML generated by DataContractSerializer throws the elements out ordered alphabetically...which does not comply with the schema. Sigh

Comment: Is it possible to tell the serializer to look at the schema and actually make something that complies with the schema (and the sequence order specified there)?

Comment: Paste your instance in the box you'll find here: freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html  Then click the button to generate a basic schema. It will validate your file. From there you can then adjust it to suit your needs (add restrictions, change types, etc.) There are also sites which do the opposite: create an instance that validates a schema that you have. But you mentioned C# classes, so what you want is probably XML binding. In that case I suggest you do some research and edit this question, or delete it and create a new one describing in detail what you want to achieve, and add a *c#* tag.